# JAVA - Highest and Lowest numbers

Tags: java

Please help me in finding the Highest and Lowest number.

I swear, I did read countless posts on the site about this problem before I decided to post the code here, because all of them had known numbers of input.

I have "unknown" input from the user. It could be any given positive or negative numbers. I am totally blank now after trying it for almost a day. Any helps is Greatly Appreciated.

```
    package test;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args){

int highest=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int lowest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter any positive or negative number");
int n = in.nextInt();

if(n > highest){
    lowest = highest;
    highest = n;
}

if (n < lowest){
    highest=lowest;
    lowest=n;
}

System.out.println(highest);
System.out.println(lowest);


    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do this input from the user?

Comment: `int highest=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int lowest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;` what does this mean? Google search `Integer.MAX_VALUE` and you will realize what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Go through your code and explain to someone how each line helps you achieve your goal.  If you can't explain a line, remove it (hint: you have some lines of code that don't make sense).  If you get stuck, ask your teacher for help.

Comment: MIN_VALUE means smallest. MAX_VALUE means largest.

Answer (score 5):

This is where your code is breaking.

```
highest=lowest;
lowest=n;
```

Now about initializing these variables.

How I, personally would start this program would be initializing both the lowest and highest with `n.` So you don't have to worry any bounds.

```
System.out.println("Enter any positive or negative number");
int n = in.nextInt();
int highest = n;
int lowest = n;

for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter any positive or negative number");
    n = in.nextInt();
    if(n > highest){
        highest = n;
    }else if (n < lowest){
        lowest=n;
    }
}

System.out.println(highest);
System.out.println(lowest);
```

This asks the user to input 10 different digits. then prints out the highest and lowest values.

`else if (n < lowest)` this could also be a `else if` because if `n` is the highest value it cant be also the lowest value because of my initialization at the start.

Answer (score 2):

1. Why are you saving the `lowest` value in the `highest` value?
2. You should define a loop
3. Complete code:

   ```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
   while(in.hasNextInt()) {
     System.out.println("Enter any positive or negative number");
     int n = in.nextInt();
     if(n > highest){
         highest = n;
     }
     if (n < lowest){
         highest=lowest;
         lowest=n;
     }
   }
   System.out.println(highest);
   System.out.println(lowest);
   ```

Comment: Oops. Thanks @Chaos for formatting

Comment: Hi Progenhard,I tried the code you provided above, sadly its not showing the result, rather keep on looping/prompting the user to enter numbers..                                                                              Hi CommuSoft, I tried the code, and it prompts only when I comment out the while loop, otherwise it does not prompt the user for input. If i enter 123456789, it outputs higheset as 123456789 and lowest 0...      I really hope that I am not doing wrong "again"... can you please check...Thanks.

Comment: If you use a file (on a descent OS) like `java --jar program.jar < file` it will work. Otherwise (if you use the `STDIN`) it will reach the end. In that case you should provide a mechanism that waits until the user has provided a number :P