# Minimum and Maximum Values from an Integer in a While Statement

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java, learning through a class, however when trying to do a while statement where someone can enter numbers between 0 and 100, until they type 999, when it then gives the number of numbers entered, the highest number, lowest number, and the average of all numbers.

The code I currently have leads to where the 999 doesn't register the first time, the highest and lowest numbers are both multi-digit numbers, the number of numbers includes any numbers outside of the limits and the 999, as does the average.

Here's what I have:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoreStatistics {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfScores = 0;
        int highest;
        int lowest;
        double average;
        Integer score = 0;
        int sumOfScores = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a grade or enter 999 to finish >> ");
        score = input.nextInt();
        sumOfScores = sumOfScores + score;

        while (score < 100 || score > 0) {
            ++numberOfScores;
            System.out.println("Please enter a grade or enter 999 to finish >> ");
            score = input.nextInt();
            sumOfScores = sumOfScores + score;
            ++numberOfScores;

            while (score > 100 || score < 0) {
                System.out.println("You entered an invalid score. Please enter a valid test score.");
                System.out.println("Please enter a grade or enter 999 to finish >> ");
                score = input.nextInt();
                sumOfScores = sumOfScores + score;

                if (score == 999) {
                    highest = score.MIN_VALUE;
                    lowest = score.MAX_VALUE;
                    average = sumOfScores / numberOfScores;
                    System.out.println("Number of Scores you entered: " + numberOfScores);
                    System.out.println("Highest Score: " + highest);
                    System.out.println("Lowest Score: " + lowest);
                    System.out.println("Average Score: " + average);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @JoeC The "How to Debug Small Programs" web site you link to does not seem appropriate for a beginner learning Java through a class.  Granted, the OP could do more to debug the program themselves.  I don't think this blog post will help them learn how to do that, not at this stage.

Comment: See this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18839041/java-highest-and-lowest-numbers

Comment: `score < 100 || score > 0` is wrong. You have to use: `score < 100 && score > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line

```
while(score < 100 || score > 0)
```

If score is `999` do you think it is included?

If you used simple debugging you would spot this immediately

Answer (score 0):

```
while (score < 100 && score > 0) {
 ++numberOfScores;
 System.out.println("Please enter a grade or enter 999 to finish>> ");
 score = input.nextInt();
 sumOfScores = sumOfScores + score;
 ++numberOfScores;
 highest=Integer.MIN_VALUE;
 lowest=Integer.MAX_VALUE;
 if(score>highest)
 highest=score;// this will find the highest , as user is entering 
 else if(score<lowest)
 lowest=score;  // this will find the highest , as user is entering

if (score == 999) {
  average = sumOfScores / numberOfScores;
  System.out.println("Number of Scores you entered: " + numberOfScores);
  System.out.println("Highest Score: " + highest);
  System.out.println("Lowest Score: " + lowest);
  System.out.println("Average Score: " + average);
 }
}
```

Comment: It would be better if you add some suggestions about your code instead of just posting some lines, that even don't make sense in this sequence.

Comment: Sorry, I just thought, the problem is lying just to calculating the highest and minimum. Extremely Sorry :(

Comment: Probably this would help :)

Comment: I am just started to use stackoverflow, so just being familiar
Thanks for telling me